# How to stop auto-completion for numbers on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to disable auto-completion for only numbers on Notepad++? I use the auto-completion for letters and words, but never use it for numbers. I was looking in the options, but could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an english version of notepad++ but I think it is:

Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Auto-Completion</kbd> >

In the popup window, there is a checkbox "Ignore numbers" (not quite sure of speling!)

Just "de"-check it. Now words will be auto-completed but numbers will not.

This is working at least for version `7.4.2`.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers all tend to be quite short, you can set autocomplete to kick in after N characters:

Settings-->Preferences-->Auto-Completion-->From Nth character